# How to check the delivery status of a message and whether it is read or not in cloud messaging android studio Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

How to check the delivery status of a message and whether it is read or not in cloud messaging android studio Firebase?
I send messages, they come, but I do not know how to check whether the message has been read or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API to track delivery status for individual messages in Firebase Cloud Messaging. If you need to know whether a user has received (or seen) a message, you should implement that in your own application logic.

One example of this is to only send [data messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages) (that are not automatically displayed by the system), handle the display of a notification for those messages yourself, track whether the user interacted with the notification, and then store that information in a cloud-hosted database.

Comment: Hello! Thank you, but how I can make it?